# Derive a formula for a curve on a lie group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group with group operation ★: $G \times G \rightarrow  G$ and Lie algebra $Lie(G)$. Each $\omega \in Lie(G)$ generates a left-invariant vector field $V$<sub>$\omega$</sub> on $G$, and that the exponential map describes the integral curves of the vector field. Specifically, the integral curve $\gamma$: $\mathbb R \rightarrow G$ of the left-invariant vector field $V$<sub>$\omega$</sub> that starts at the point $x \in G$ at time $t = 0$ is given by:

$$\gamma(t) \triangleq x ★\text{exp}(t\omega)$$

This equation provides a prescription for "moving around" on the Lie group $G$ along
the "direction" determined by $\omega$. Say a point $x \in G$ lies in the image of $G's$ exponential map, we write $\log(x)$ to denote one of $x$'s preimages, so that:
$$x = \text{exp}(\log(x))$$

If $G's$ exponential map is surjective, then there is always at least one choice of $\log(x) \in Lie(G)$ that will satisfy $x = $exp$(\log(x))$.
Now suppose that $x, y \in G$ and that $G$'s exponential map is surjective. Using $\gamma(t) \triangleq x ★$exp$(t\omega)$, I want to derive a formula for a curve $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow G$ such that $\gamma (0) = x$ and $\gamma (1) = y$

Comment: Did you try it for $G = \mathbb S^1$?

Comment: For any path $\phi$ in $\frak{g}$ from $X$ to $Y$ with $\exp(X) = x$ and $\exp(Y) = y$, $\exp \circ \phi$ is a path such as you require. This doesn't need an integral curve specifically. If you want to make it an integral curve simply take the integral curve from $0$ to $x^{-1}y$ and left translate it (so $\omega$ would be some logarithm of $x^{-1}y$)